# Create java-like document for function in IOS (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, ios5, document

I'm beginner with `IOS` developing and I'm using `Xcode`. In java (android), I can create `document` for a function like below:

```
 /**
 * Get the index object in list of object and try to catch
 * {@link IndexOutOfBoundsException}
 * 
 * @param list
 *            of object: {@link List}
 * @param index
 *            of ojbect: {@link Integer}
 * @return Object or null if {@link IndexOutOfBoundsException} occurs
 */
public static <T> T getIndexObject(List<T> list, int index) {
    T object = null;
    try {
        object = list.get(index);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return object;
}
```

When I create `document` as above (in Java), every time when I hover the mouse over the function (used in every where), I will see the document of that function. How's about `IOS` in `Xcode`? I know `Doxygen`, but It only generate `HTML` files (that not what I want). I want document like default document of every function that provided by `Apple` (when `Ctrl + click` on a function of IOS SDK)? Can I do it? And how? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use [AppleDoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/). They have an article on their site that explains how to integrate with Xcode: http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc-docs-examples-xcode/, basically, you use:

```
appledoc
--project-name appledoc
--project-company "Gentle Bytes"
--company-id com.gentlebytes
--output ~/help
--logformat xcode
.
```

to generate the documents. You can also do the normal HTML in addition. It's free and looks a lot like Apple's documentation.